# linux: get a script to be able to ask the user for a file name then open that file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need a linux script to ask the user if they want to use the program and then if yes it needs to ask the user what file they would like to search for. At the moment, I have created two files called `terminal` and `pi` to test my script on.

The expected outcome of the program would be:

```
welcome
would you like to find a file?(if yes type 'y' if no type 'n'
```

If yes, it should continue to ask what file they would like to find then it should print that file.

So far I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash

hello "welcome!"
while [ "$hello" != "n" ]

do
    echo "would you like to find a file?(if yes type 'y' if no type'n'"
    read hello
    case $hello in
        y)      echo "what is the name of the file?"
                    read option
                    ***this is where the code i dont know should theroecticaly be***
        n)      echo "goodbye"
    esac
done
```

Like I said, the expected outcome is that it will print the file. How can this be done?

Comment: you need to be more specific about "opening" the file. You can use `cat filename` to just "dump" the file into the terminal, or maybe you mean to open file in an editor? Then you have to ask the user which editor they like (`vi, vim, pico, gedit, etc, etc`). Read up on the shell's `select` command. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have an error there:

```
hello "welcome"
```

That doesn't do anything unless you have a command on your system called `hello`. To print a message, use

```
echo "welcome"
```

To get input from the user after printing a message, use `read`. Since you're using `bash`, you can use the `-p` option to present a message and save user input with one command:

```
read -p message" variable
```

To find and display the contents of the file, you can use the `find` command and its `-exec` option. For example, `-exec less` to display the file using `less`.

Then, you have various other errors. A working version of your script would be something like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'Welcome!'

while [ "$response" != "n" ]
do
    read -p "Would you like to find a file? [y/n]:" response
    case $response in
        y) read -p "What is the name of the file? " file
            find . -type f -name "$file" -exec less {} \;
                    ;;

        n)     
            echo "goodbye" 
            exit ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `find` command. Read the `man` page of find command.

```
find <dir_name> -name ${option}
```

If you want to `find` the file and display its contents:

```
find <dir_name> -name ${option} | xargs cat
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
find . -name "<filename>" | xargs vim
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a program that asks the user to enter a file name. As much as
there is no file the program is still running

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).