# Linux:searching for a string inside a text file that the user has all ready entered the name of

Tags: linux, string, bash, text, grep

Hello i have got the string as shown bellow and it all worked fine but then i remembered that i needed to add in a command so the user can search for a string that is inside the file they want to view. I tryed using grep but i don't know how to use grep well. I need the user to enter a file name and then enter the bit of string and it needs to report if the string i in the file. The programs i am using to test this are called pi and terminal. If you can help it would be amazing. the expected outcome is that it will show the text file and tell you if the string you entered is in that string file.

my code so far is this i have highlighted the bit i dont know (grep):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo 'Welcome!'

while [ "$response" != "n" ]
do
    read -p "Would you like to find a file? [y/n]:" response
    case $response in
        y) read -p "What is the name of the file? " file
            read grep "text string to search” $file         
                $grep "redeem reward" $file    
           find . -type f -name "$file" -exec less {} \;
                    ;;

        n)
            echo "goodbye"
            exit ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: why are you using `find`?

Comment: what would surgest i change it to?

Comment: if you want to search inside the file, `find` is not what you should be using

Comment: @nu11p01n73R: Because he's [inching his way forward](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117682)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    y) read -p "What is the name of the file? " file
        read grep "text string to search” $file         
            $grep "redeem reward" $file    
       find . -type f -name "$file" -exec less {} \;
                ;;
```

This is broken in several ways.

```
        read grep "text string to search” $file
```

Why `grep`? And why reading into the same variable as the filename (`$file`)? Oh, and when giving a variable to `read`, do *not* use the `$` for dereferencing (you did that right in the first line...)

And as user Biffen commented quire rightly, that second quotation mark isn't correct either. Most programming languages are quite picky, and accept only ASCII 0x22 as "true" quotation mark, so you should stick to that.

```
            $grep "redeem reward" $file
```

You don't have a *variable* that's named `grep`, so `$grep` is nonsense. Besides, I thought you wanted to grep for the *entered* string?

```
       find . -type f -name "$file" -exec less {} \;
```

OK, I guess you're just confused now.

Try this:

```
    y) read -p "What is the name of the file: " file
       read -p "Text string to search: " text         
       grep -F "$text" $file
       ;;
```

The `-F` option to `grep` uses `$text` as fixed string instead of a pattern. Drop it if that is not what you want.

> i don't know how to use grep well.

For that, there's [`man grep`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep). Try it on your command line, it's there. (In case you're looking for `man read`, that's a builtin command to the bash shell, so use `man bash` and skip to the "`SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS`" section.

Comment: There's also a wrong type of quotation mark in there: `”` instead of `"`.

Comment: @Biffen: Good catch, I didn't see that as I did this "dry" (i.e. copy & paste & comment without really running the code).